# Saving list in file as int and when reading why is it in string?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, readline, readlines

I am saving a integer list to file with

```html
number = [3808640804, 552553035, 815157969, 1623809649, 1851153805, 4058081409, 2438887622, 2833416221, 1727496343, 3172042750]
txt =  f"H:\data_set\\testing\\1K\chunk.txt"
with open(txt, 'w', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as filee:
    for line in number:
        filee.write(f"{line}\n")
```

But When I read the file using script

```html
txt =  f"H:\data_set\\testing\\1K\chunk.txt"
with open(txt, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore', buffering=100000) as filee:
    g = filee.readlines()

print(type(g[1]))
print(g[0:10])
```

I get this output:

```html
<class 'str'>
['3808640804\n', '552553035\n', '815157969\n', '1623809649\n', '1851153805\n', '4058081409\n', '2438887622\n', '2833416221\n', '1727496343\n', '3172042750\n']
```

Whereas I should get this output:

```html
[3808640804, 552553035, 815157969, 1623809649, 1851153805, 4058081409, 2438887622, 2833416221, 1727496343, 3172042750]
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try reading the file with this code :

```
with open(txt, 'r') as filee:
    numbers = [int(line.strip()) for line in filee]
print(numbers)
```